# React Native RNPicker select

Tags: react-native

i am using RNPicker Select in which i want dropdown items to get from api but i am getting empty dropdown with no values
following is my code

```
class Component extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
  inqSourceList: [],
}

componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchSource();

  }
fetchSource = () => {
getInqSourceList('view=select', this, null)
}

  <RNPickerSelect
                  items={this.state.inqSourceList}
                  name="source"
                  value={this.state.source ? this.state.source.id : null}
                  onValueChange={value => {
                    this.setState({
                      source:value,
                    });
                  }}
                  style={{marginBottom: 10}}
                  
                />
```

and my api code is

```
  export async function getModuleList  (moduleName, params,error) {
  let token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('token');
    axios
      .get(BASE_URL + moduleName + "?" + params, {

        headers: {
           Accept: 'application/json',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
           Authorization: "Bearer " + token },
      })
      .then((res) => {
      
          var bytes = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(res.data.toString(), ENCDEC);
          res.data = JSON.parse(bytes.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8));
          // success(res.data);
      //  console.log(res.data)
      })
      .catch(error);
  }
```

in this i am getting values from backend when i use console.log(res.data) i get list of options..but the dropdown item is empty..
thanks

here is the function where inqSourceList is set

```
  export function getInqSourceList(params, _this, next) {
    getModuleList('settings/inquiry-source', params, data => {
      _this.setState({inqSourceList: data.rows});
      if (next) next(data);
    });
  }
```

Comment: where u set inqSourceList ?

Comment: i have edited my question

Comment: put all your file , you are using setState out of react component ?, In module data you get the data as well or not ?

Comment: i am getting the data

Comment: i have used setState inside my server file

Comment: put all the code you have the picker seems like its fine. In getModuleList callback you get the data as well right ?

Comment: yes i get data from backened

Comment: i have edited my full code..thanks

Comment: The problem is that you are using setState outside of a react component that is not recommended is error prone but if you want that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45688201/setstate-use-state-in-external-function-react